# Deploying custom SharePoint workflow to production server

Tags: workflow

I have created a Visual Studio sequential workflow on my test server and also created a custom activity for it.  How do I deploy these to the production server (or another server?  I created a WSP, and activated the workflow on a new server/site collection,  but I receive an error when the workflow runs. I am new to SharePoint development, so any suggestions is greatly appreciated...

I use following link to develop this workflow:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/419004/Deploying-Workflow-as-WSP-File

Is there something else that I should do?

Comment: What error are you receiving on deploying this on new server?

Comment: I get the error failed on start (retrying) or something like that.  But I think it is because it is  a farm solution and I tried to install it as a sandboxed one.  I plan to try Powershell at work next week.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry, the error actually was "An error occurred in" + workflow name.  My memory failed me.

Answer (score 2):

As I have understood you have created a farm solution (not sandbox, because code-based workflows couldn't be created in sandbox), but the link you have provided is related to the sandbox deployment. You need to use PowerShell (+Central admin if you want) for farm deployment.

You can take a look how to do it [here](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/deploy-sharepoint-2010-solution-wsp-package-usin-59.aspx).
After adding WSP using PowerShell comand (Step 2 in article) you can deploy it using Central Admin \ System settings \ Manage farm solutions

If you have some additional questions - ask me, I'll try to explain it in more details.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It is a farm solution. I never thought of that. I will try PowerShell next week at work.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but was told I need 15 reputation points.  I'm really new to the forum.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: So, I upvoted on behalf of user13788